# Riddley Search in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra

I am working on a ruby script to get a list of servers in a node group. When I use the following query, I can get the results

```
ridley.search(:node, "role:#{chef_role} AND chef_environment:#{env}").each { |n|
```

But, when I search with the following,

```
ridley.search(:node, "role:#{chef_role} AND chef_environment:#{env} AND service_type:#{service_type}").each { |n|
```

I get the following error

> [2018-04-17T10:37:58.763287 #17333] ERROR -- : Actor crashed!
>   Ridley::Errors::HTTPBadRequest: {"error":["invalid search query:

How can I add the extra "service_type" and get a successful search?

Comment: Ridley is deprecated and no longer being maintained, don’t use it.

Comment: Use the chef-api gem instead, though that’s only marginally maintained.

Comment: Thanks @coderanger. I will check with chef-api gem